# How to get the 3D intersection between a Line and a raster in PostGIS?

Tags: raster, postgis, postgresql, geotiff-tiff, 3d

I successfully loaded a Geotiff `.tif` file into PostGIS using `raster2pgsql`, split into 20x20 tiles with the following command:

```
raster2pgsql -s {srid} -I -C -M -t 20x20 {tif_file_path} {table_name} > output.sql
```

And then I successfully loaded the `output.sql` file into my database.

Let's say I have a 3D line as follows:

```
ST_MakeLine(st_pointz(X,Y,Z, SRID),
            st_pointz(X,Y,Z, SRID))
```

It seems like [ST_3DIntersection](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_3DIntersection.html) only supports geometries.
How can I get the 3D intersection between this line and the rasters in the DB?

Comment: You need to make a 3d polygons or 3d points from your raster, then you can use st_3dintersection